# Remove all child nodes from the parent except one specific, an xml in c #

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is Xml

```
 <ItemWarehouseInfo>
      <row>
        <MinimalStock>0.000000</MinimalStock>
        <MaximalStock>0.000000</MaximalStock>
        <MinimalOrder>0.000000</MinimalOrder>
        <StandardAveragePrice>0.000000</StandardAveragePrice>
        <Locked>tNO</Locked>
        <WarehouseCode>Mc</WarehouseCode>
        <DefaultBinEnforced>tNO</DefaultBinEnforced>
      </row>
      ...other equal lines
    </ItemWarehouseInfo>
```

I have to remove all child nodes from every row node except for the WarehouseCode node
I tried this method but obviously I'm wrong and nothing changes:

```
    XDocument xdoc = XmlHelper.LoadXDocFromString(xmlOITM);
XElement magaRow = xdoc.Root.Descendants(Constants.Articoli.ART_MAGA_NODES).FirstOrDefault();//ItemWarehouseInfo node
List<XElement> row = magaRow.Elements().ToList();//row node
foreach(XElement child in row.Elements())
{
    if (child.Name != "WarehouseCode")
    {
        child.Remove();
    }
}
```

This is the final result that I expect:

```
<ItemWarehouseInfo>
      <row>
        <WarehouseCode>Mc</WarehouseCode>
      </row>
      ...other equal lines
</ItemWarehouseInfo>
```

Comment: Just my personal taste but I'd go with Xsl for tasks like this. If you are interested, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
doc.Descendants("row")
   .Elements()
   .Where(e => e.Name != "WarehouseCode")
   .Remove();
```

#### Explanation:

- `doc.Descendants("row")` - Finds all row elements no matter how deep they are.
- `Elements()` - Gets all immediate children elements
- `Where()` - Gets all elements whose name is not `WarehouseCode`
- `Remove()` - Deletes all found elements

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TânNguyễn Added explanation 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `.Elements()` for each row, you already got the list of elements:

```
foreach(XElement child in row)
{
    if (child.Name != "WarehouseCode")
    {
        child.Remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: @r.pezzolati, it works for me, xdoc is modified. You'll need to clarify what exactly you mean by "doesn't work"...

Comment: The Xml remain the same

Answer (score 0):

Get row, remove it. Create new row, add the row's WarehouseCode, and then add that row to the magaRow. If this doesn't work, I suspect namespaces are causing issues.

```
XElement row = magaRow.Element("row");
row.Remove();
XElement newRow = new XElement("row");
newRow.Add(row.Element("WarehouseCode"));
magaRow.Add(newRow);
```